# On recurring billing, is it possible to get declined payments back?

Tags: payment, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

In our system we use Automated Recurring Billing for our members. We check our users subscription status from Recurring Billing API. We check failed payments from Transaction Reporting API and it appears that some of the subscriptions status code return “active” from API even not charged. Let me give a scenario about it :

A user has an ARB monthly subscription which payment cycle is 14th of every month. User has been successfully charged for 3 months. But on 4th payment, we saw that the payment failed and response code from API is “this transaction has been declined”. We think that credit card expiration info may be failed and user may update it. So we put the user in a grace period(two days) and let user update credit card information. If user updates credit card information in two days we call API to update subscription with new credit card info. Let’s say this update subscription request is done on 16th of the current month. Can we get the payment which has passed on 14th ? Or has user been charged on 16th which update subscription request is sent and is ARB payment cycle changed from now on ? Or user will be charged on the next month and we can not get failed payment ?

I could not find any details about failed transactions payment flow when credit card info is updated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A failed subscription payment won't be retried after you update the customer profile.  However, you can use the updated custer profile to make your own one-time payment.